# Swift 3 Management of title for header in section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewController as

```
class MyController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate
```

I set the dataSource and the delegate using the Storyboard
and in this class I have implemented the methods:

1. tableView titleForHeaderInSection
2. tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle
3. sectionIndexTitles.

I want to implement an app with the same behavior as the contact app.
But the problem is that the section title is seems detached from the list, if I scroll the list the section title doesn't slide...

[image]

any help would be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is a matter of constraints, i solve this problem using the StackView. I put the SearchBar and the UITableView inside the StackView and in this way i get the vertical alignment. Now it's work.
[image]